# Android Permissions - Only request read contacts, if Android version > 5

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I added contacts permissions to my app, and noticed a steep decline in people who downloaded the app after viewing the listing in Google Play. Contact permission is not necessary, so I've already implemented the latest conditional contact permission code, for Android M.

What I'd like to do, is make it so that the user never sees the permissions Contacts requested from Google Play. But I would still like to be able to prompt the user's with Android M or higher for contact permission, once they access a part of the app that requires contacts.

Is this possible to only request contact permission on demand, and not request it at all for lower versions of Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`<uses-permission-sdk-23>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html) attribute in place of `<uses-permission>` to request a permission *only* on API 23 and higher devices.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it makes sense, but it doesn't actually seem to work. When I use `<uses-permission>` with READ_CONTACTS, and prompt for permission, I'm asked to allow or deny the permission. However, when I just replace `<uses-permission>` with `<uses-permission-sdk23>`, I'm never prompted even though the java code didn't change at all?  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying this on a clean install?

Comment: Yes, just tried with a clean install, with same result. Never see a prompt with this line in the manifest: `<uses-permission-sdk23 android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`. Simply changing it to `uses-permission` includes a prompt, but the obviously also demands contacts permissions for all devices.

Comment: In case it matters, minSdkVersion = 15, and targetSdkVersion = compileSdkVersion = 23

Comment: Looks like the documentation is wrong - it should actually be `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` (note the last hyphen) as per [this bug comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189841#c7)

Comment: Fantastic! Just noticed that android studio catches the issue if you hover over the "sdk23" piece. Just tested this and I'm getting the prompt correctly, thanks a lot!